# /var/run/docker.sock symlink is missing after a reboot

Tags: kali-linux, docker

Recently I moved to `docker desktop` from `docker cli`(docker.io) & I have changed my default context to docker desktop which is at `$HOME/.docker/desktop/` but I was still getting `/var/run/docker.sock` not found. So I created a symbolic link to the desktop socket to `/var/run/docker.sock`. But after every reboot, I get `/var/run/docker.sock` not found. So I have to make the symlink again & again to get any work done. I'm not a symlink guru. Is this behaviour normal? If so what is the fix here?

#### System Information

```bash
Linux kali 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.5.6-1kali1 (2023-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1 more thing. I don't see my `docker-cli` containers in the `docker desktop`.

Comment: That shouldn't be a symlink, but a socket. You probably have to start our at least addictive the docket service to get it. Kali seems the wrong distro for this kind of work. How did you install docker?

Comment: Docker Cli has been working fine for me for the past 4 years or so. Recently I moved because of some dev work I'm doing. Need to handle the containers manually which helps if there is a GUI.

Comment: What can I do to make it work or any temporary solution ?

Comment: /var/run is cleaned after each reboot. The directory it is used to see if there are blocked or crashed processes (or also real processes to send signals). After reboot there is high probability that processes have same ID (or similar one), so we need to clean it, not to confuse old and new state

Comment: Is there a way to make the docker desktop create the socket or anything? I mean we can create a login script but I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: How is your dockerd service launched ? This is what is meant to create the /var/run/docker.pid & docker.sock. If you have moved the data-root (in the service file) you cannot see any previous image. Else you recreate them from Dockerfile or you can move what's inside /var/lib/docker in the new data-root. ExecStart in service is something like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --data-root=/data/docker/data`

Comment: I choose the option `start on startup` on docker desktop. But that was not working that's why I made it a startup application. It this is the issue ?

Comment: .. why in blazes are you running *kali* as a desktop/server/docker controller distro?

Comment: I mostly do pentesting stuff. But recently I have had to do some work with the containers that's why I'm using Kali. I don't do much heavy DevOps work, to be honest.